# Prestashop google analytics goal tracking

Tags: google-analytics, prestashop

I'm having problem with my analytics setup on my prestashop install. First ga only showed the general files "category.php" and "product.php" instead of specific categories and products. I solved this through [this post](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/172576-google-analytics-tracking/page__p__859789#entry859789).

However, the goal doesnt seem to trigger on order. I have set up a goal with match type **head match** on "/order-confirmation.php" but it doesnt trigger. Also order-confirmation.php doesnt show anywhere in the statistics even though i got several orders.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Find the goal page in your Google Analytics and then update the head match to whatever it shows.

To find what page is firing, submit a test order and use the [Google Analytics Debugger for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
It seems order-confirmation.php simply doesnt get tracked. It is nowhere to be found. I found a resource implying it's a bug in prestashop:

Comment: @Viktor : could you eventually let us know this resource ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings to "begins with" and reverify. It worked for me.